# Input Method Manager Functions - correct call order for Hiragana to Kanji candidates list c++ covnersion

Tags: c++, winapi, ime

I'm trying to convert the Hiaragana characters to candidates list (Kanji). Looks like it should be possible by using the Input Method Manager Functions but it doesn't work as I expected.
I installed the Japanese Language pack and I'm able to open IME in the text editor so some functionalities should be enabled.

In src we have sth like:

```
HIMC context = ImmCreateContext();//non-NULL result
bool result = ImmSetOpenStatus(context, true);//result == true
std::wstring wstr = L"こいび";//Hiragana string for conversion
result = ImmSetConversionStatus(context, IME_CMODE_JAPANESE, IME_SMODE_NONE);//result == true
result = ImmSetCompositionString(context, SCS_SETSTR, (LPVOID)wstr.c_str(), wstr.length(), NULL, 0);//result == true
DWORD listCount = 0;
DWORD lpdResult = 0;
lpdResult = ImmGetCandidateListCount(context, &listCount);//listCount == 0, lpdResult  == 144
```

Looks like it works somehow but I'm always getting similar results (I checked it for standard letters, shorter JPN string and by creating std::string + conversion to wstring).
Unfortunately I didn't found example related to it so maybe I didn't call something or I called something in wrong order.
The [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318649(v=vs.85).aspx) contains not too much details about it so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: `ldpResult` isn't zero, so why aren't you calling [ImmGetCandidateList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318545.aspx)? And *"M$"*? Seriously?

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately the ImmGetCandidateList returns 0 - so looks like I did something wrong earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Imm function must use in window message loop.

for example,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Imm/nf-imm-immgetcandidatelistcounta
look remark part.

"Applications typically call this function in response to an IMN_OPENCANDIDATE or IMN_CHANGECANDIDATE command."

when message loop type is "IMN_OPENCANDIDATE" or "IMN_CHANGECANDIDATE", you can use immgetcandidatelistcount function.